# strange character &tstr; in xml, what is that ?Is it a HTML encoded character?

Tags: unicode, html-encode

my program received a story which contains many `&tstr;` 
It doesn't seems like a HTML encoded character like `＆nbsp;`

I [searched on Google](https://www.google.co.id/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=tNMQVdqUAtDVuQT3qICgCg#q=%26tstr%3B+) and see many articles contain this character.

So what is it? Is it a HTML encoded character?

Comment: Wierd.  lancasteronline.com, http://www.republicanccc.com, www.ephratareview.com, lititzrecord.com, and thetruthaboutplas.com seem to be using it like a comma.  docs.autodesk.com and forums.cgsociety.org are using it as an XML tag.

Comment: @MooingDuck yeah, and also i can see many Swedish websites using it, so i also think it related to Swedish language, because my program mainly dealing with Swedish stories.

Comment: I had skipped over the swedish on the assumption that tstr was part of a word or something, but looking again, you're right, they're using it as some sort of sentence break: a comma, hyphen, or colon or something.

Comment: Can you provide a URL to a specific HTML page that actually uses `&tstr;` (and renders it correctly)?

Answer (score 0):

`&tstr;` is not a standard pre-defined entity in either XML or HTML, so it has to be a custom entity defined in a DTD that is associated with the story you are downloading.